# Bad owner or permissions on ~./ssh/config after upgrade to Windows 1809

Tags: windows, ssh, file-permissions, windows-10

I'm using Windows 10 OpenSSH version. After update to Windows 1809 I've got

```
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe myhost
Bad owner or permissions on C:\\Users\\XXX/.ssh/config
```

But execution

```
c:\Windows.old\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe myhost
```

is successful.

Versions are slightly different

```
C:\Windows.old\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
```

I've tried to 'cleanup' permissions like [described](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1763#issuecomment-386505264) but it doesn't help.

Comment: I have everything in place and owner and file permissions are the same. I find out a kind of workaround: uninstall OpenSSH build and using ssh build included in latest git-for-windows installation

Comment: Take a look at [Cygwin sshd vs Microsoft sshd](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2018-10/msg00055.html) on the Cygwin mailing list; and [sshd issues on Windows 10 version 1803](https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2018-06/msg00249.html) on the Sourceware mailing list. It looks like the fix is in the works, but the author says it may take a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by changing file's DACL (permissions) by removing inheritance and leaving only the user, SYSTEM and Administrators to have Full control access:

```
icacls C:\Users\xxx\.ssh\config
C:\Users\xxx\.ssh\config NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                            BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                            DOMAIN\xxx:(I)(F)
```

I used explorer's GUI for that, but it can be done by icacls as well.
Example:

```
> icacls.exe .\.ssh\config /grant everyone:f 
> ssh 127.0.0.1
Bad owner or permissions on C:\\Users\\xxx/.ssh/config
> icacls.exe .\.ssh\config /inheritance:d
> icacls.exe .\.ssh\config /remove everyone
> ssh 127.0.0.1
ssh 127.0.0.1
Warning: Permanently added '127.0.0.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
xxx@127.0.0.1's password:
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, after the upgrade to 1809 Windows installed it's own ssh.exe.
Ssh delivered with Cygwin works just fine:

There are following ssh.exe installed:

```
C:\Users\ebajgrz\.ssh>where ssh
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
c:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.exe
```

The ssh client from Windows complains about permissions:

```
C:\Users\ebajgrz\.ssh>C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe myserver
Bad owner or permissions on C:\\Users\\ebajgrz/.ssh/config
```

Cygwin's ssh works just fine:

```
C:\Users\ebajgrz\.ssh>C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.exe myserver
Last login: Wed Feb 19 09:01:35 2020 from 100.93.177.156
[ebajgrz@myserver ~]$
```